# Issue with importing Mailboxes on Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server

We currently have a couple of issues with our Exchange Server. Maybe one of you guys is able to help.

We are trying to import a mailbox to an mail account. We did use

The Command:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics -Identity "j.doe"
```

delivers the following result:

```
Name:   MailboxImport
Target: StalledDueToTarget_MailboxCapacityExceeded 
TargetAlias:     j.doe
PercentComplete: 0
```

In the ecp we have the following Information regarding mailbox usage:

```
4.35MB used, 0% from 10GB.
```

We found a fixed that should work but didn't really get us back on track with this issue:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MailboxImportRequest | Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics -IncludeReport | fl Report
```

with the following report:

```
Report : 08.05.2019 16:51:40 [exchange01] 'domain.tld/Domain Users/Admin': Anforderung erstellt.
```

'Anforderung erstellt' translates to something like 'Request created'.

Do you guys have an idea how we are able to get the data into the mailbox? We did this already with a couple of mailboxes and never had an issue.

Also: the mailbox we are trying to import isn't larger then 5GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently, the import process took longer than expected. It just started on it's own.